# Format a date in html from a MySQL param

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL param in this format `"date_format":"M d, Y l"` and the current output is:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <p class="nspInfo nspInfo1 tleft fnone">Oct 12, 2015 Monday</p>
</div>
```

The PHP code used:

```
if(
    ($config['news_content_info_pos'] != 'disabled' && $num == 1) || 
    ($config['news_content_info2_pos'] != 'disabled' && $num == 2)
) {
    $news_info = '<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><p class="nspInfo '.$class.'">'.$config['info'.(($num == 2) ? '2' : '').'_format'].'</p></div>';

    $info_date = JHTML::_('date', $item['date'], $config['date_format']);
```

and

```
$news_info = str_replace('%DATE', $info_date, $news_info);
```

I know line 5 of the PHP code above calls the param but I don't know how to add the span with correct classes so the output is in my desired style. How should I proceed?

My desire output is with different span and classes as shown below:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <p class="nspInfo nspInfo1 tleft fnone">
        <span class="dt">Oct 12</span>, 
        <span class="yr">2015</span> 
        <span class="dy">Monday</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your request, you can try using this simple approach

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
<p class="nspInfo nspInfo1 tleft fnone">
    <span class="dt"><?php echo date("M j") ?></span>, 
    <span class="yr"><?php echo date("Y") ?></span> 
    <span class="dy"><?php echo date("l") ?></span>
</p>
```

Hope it works?

Comment: $news_info = '<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><p class="nspInfo '.$class.'"><span><?php echo date("M j") ?></span></p></div>';

Nothing shows up. No error. Just blank!